# Ambiguity of 姿勢 in constructions like 頑張ろうという姿勢

Tags: translation

I just have a simple question about volitional verbs + という + 姿勢. I know that 姿勢 means both 'posture' and 'attitude', so I just wanted to get a clarification on whether something like 頑張ろうという姿勢 is a *description of an observable state of affairs* (e.g., you see that the person is heaving, sweating, and concentrating) or is something more *figurative* (e.g., the person may not show physical signs of exertion, but you intuit their psychological state as one being of exertion). Or are both interpretations possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter. 姿勢 used like this doesn't refer to a physical posture. It almost certainly refers to an overall attitude. In a rare case where you want to mean the former, you can say something like 頑張ろうという体勢.